# split regular expression php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like that :

```
 0d(Hi)i(Hello)4d(who)i(where)540d(begin)i(began)
```

And i want to make it an array with that.
I try first to add separator, in order to use the php function explode.

```
 ;0,d(Hi),i(Hello);4,d(who),i(where);540,d(begin),i(began)
```

It works but the problem is I want to minimize the separator to save disk space.
Therefore i want to know by using preg_split, regular expression, if it's possible to have a huge array like that without using separator :

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => d(hi) [2] => i(Hello) ) 
         [1] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => d(who) [2] => i(where) )
         [2] => Array ( [0] => 540 [1] => d(begin) [2] => i(began) )
       )
```

I try some code & regex, but I saw that the value in the regular expression was not present in the final result (like explode function, in the final array we do not have the delimitor.)

More over, i have some difficulties to build the regex. Here is the one that I made :

```
 $modif = preg_split("/[0-9]+(d(.+))?(i(.+))?/", $data);
```

I must precise that d() and i() can not be present (but at least one)

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that `d(...)` or `i(...)` may not always be present? If both are present, are they always in that order?

Comment: yeah. always d before i, but d can be absent, and i can be absent but not both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)(d\([^()]*\))?(i\([^()]*\))?/', $subject, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

on your original string, then you'll get an array where

```
$result[$i][0]
```

contains the `i`th match (i. e. `$result[0][0]` would be `0d(Hi)i(Hello)`) and where

```
$result[$i][$c]
```

contains the `c`th capturing group of the `i`th match (i. e. `$result[0][1]` is `0`, `$result[0][2]` is `d(Hi)` and `$result[0][2]` is `i(Hello)`).

Is that what you wanted?